# Changing mic levels on Linux with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, audio

I'd like to create a simple program on Linux in order to adjust and fix the microphone level setting.

I'd like my program to, whenever my Mic level drops below 0.5, automatically revert it to 0.7 (for example).

Problem is: I don't know how to access these configurations on Ubuntu Linux with C++. I thought about using bash commands within my C++ code, but still need to read the mic level setting. How can my C++ program access these microphone audio settings, read and change them?

In college I just learn algoritms, but never how to make the programming language work with the system.

Thank You!

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127744/how-to-fetch-data-from-a-usb-microphone-in-c-or-c

Comment: The widget you are showing is probably open source. You can find and study its source code if you are interested.

Comment: Asking  for recommendations of libraries is off-topic.